# sticky navbar - to only show on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I want to make the button sticky on mobile devices only – something like this on the demo [link](http://www.cimbbank.com.my/en/personal/products/cards/credit-cards/find-the-right-cards/cimb-petronas-mastercard.html?mobile=yes&at_preview=4SZM4c0PPlcgMeFsLRPVyaxxfuAHrt)

You will have to resize your browser to mobile dimension in order to see this. Basically this is how it is expected -
On landing page you can see the buttons are underneath the banner and when scrolls down it will be sticky on top:
[stickynav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgtD8.png)

I want to have this sticky on mobile but right now it's happening on desktop. Could you anyone advise if there’s any impact or how to achieve buttons sticky on mobile devices only?

Also will there be any impact to desktop version on how the buttons gonna be placed?

Comment: which part you want to stick in mobile view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35605310/5383669 refer this link to use media queries.

Answer (score 2):

let say you have a button

```
<button class="for-mobile"></button
```

you need to hide this button first

```
.for-mobile {display:none;}
```

and display it when screen is resized

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1020px)
.for-mobile {
    display: block !important;
}
```

change the max-width to adjust when this style is applied

Answer (score 0):

You should use css **@media** queries.
Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you see the source code of the website, you can easily understand that it is using a class `.non-mobile` in the header div

```
<div class="row t-most-header non-mobile">
```

and given the **CSS** :

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 1020px)
   {
     .non-mobile
    {
       display:none !important
    }
  }
```

Learn more about media queries [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)